# Python helium get contents of table after click

Tags: python, web-scraping, helium

I am using helium to scrape a webpage.

```
result = start_firefox(                                                                                   
    "https://www.medtronic.com/covidien/en-us/products/brain-monitoring/bis-monitoring-system.html",      
)                                                                                                         
                                                                                                          
result.find_element_by_class_name("js-open-table-overlay").click()
```

After the click action i am presented with a table and i need to scrape the contents of the table but How do i select the table after the click ?

Comment: if it it `<table>` then you can find `<tr>` to get all rows, and for every row find `<td>` to get values in row.

Comment: as I remeber from your previous question - this table is all time in HTML and you can use `find_element_by_...` to get values from this table even without clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `find_elements_...` to get all `<table>`, and use `for`-loop to work with every table separatelly amd use (nested) `for`-loop to get `<tr>` (row) and `<th>` (header) in table, and use (nested) `for`-loop to get `<td>` (cell) in row. And you would have to add elements to correct (nested) lists.

---

But this page uses normal `<table>` and this table is all time in HTML (not added by javaScript) so it can be simpler to use `pandas.read_html()` to get all `<table>`

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.medtronic.com/covidien/en-us/products/brain-monitoring/bis-monitoring-system.html"

all_tables = pd.read_html(url)

for table in all_tables:
    print(table.to_string())
```

Result

```
     ORDER CODE                                                      DESCRIPTION UNIT OF MEASURE  QUANTITY
0      186-1014                        BIS™ Complete 4-Channel Monitoring System            Each         1
1      186-0210                                  BIS™ Complete 2-Channel Monitor            Each         1
2  186-0224-AMS  BIS™ LOC 4-Channel Monitor with Patient Interface Cable (PIC-4)            Each         1
3  186-0195-AMS          BIS™ LOC 2-Channel Monitor with Patient Interface Cable            Each         1
4      186-0212                                            BIS™ Bilateral Sensor            Each         1

              DISPLAY                                               BIS™ COMPLETE 2-CHANNEL MONITOR                                     BIS™ COMPLETE 4-CHANNEL MONITORING SYSTEM
0          Parameters                                                    BIS, SQI, EMG, SR, BC, EEG                                           BIS, SQI, EMG, SR, BC, TP, SEF, EEG
1  Trended parameters                                                         BIS, SQI, EMG, SR, BC                                                    BIS, SQI, EMG, SR, BC, SEF
2          BIS™ alarm  Upper and lower limit, results in visual and audible alert when out of range  Upper and lower limit, results in visual and audible alert when out of range
```

Comment: `pandas` can get only text from simple, classic `<table>` but some pages use `<div>` or `<li`> to format data in table. And it can't get `attributes` and text from other tags inside table.